# How to list files ignored by git due to .git/info/exclude

Tags: git

I have some files with a certain pattern that I usually want to ignore so I put it in `.git/info/exclude`. However, sometimes they could be outdated or too big etc, so I do want to have a way to list them one by one so that I can pipe to another command for some processing.

However, I don't think git provides this functionality out of the box. Do you guys have some nice solutions that achieve this?

Comment: This is not GITs responsibillity. Use whatever scripting tool your environment supports (bash or powershell). GIT is just a source control application

Comment: `git status --ignored`, `git ls-files --others` ???

Comment: Note, there is the globally ignore file `.gitignore` and locally ignore file `.git/info/exclude` and I only want those _additional_ files ignored by `.git/info/exclude` but not those by `.gitignore`

Comment: Yes, it is git's responsibility. `git status --ignored` lists all ignores.